# Segmentation fault before main is executed

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, stack-overflow

For some reason I am getting a segmentation fault before any of my code is actually executed in the main() function. I have tried following the line of execution by putting in printfs but nothing is actually executed. I don't see anything in my program that would be causing a stack overflow, as I hardly even use memory.

If someone has better eyes than me and can spot this error it would be very much appreciated!

Main:

```
#include "../inc/protos.h"


HistogramData *histogram_data;
bool signal_caught = false;
sem_t *semaphore_id;
int letter_count[kLetterCount] = { 0 };
int wait_time = 0;

int main(void)
{
    int shared_memory_id = 0;
    key_t shared_memory_key = 0;
    char buffer[kBufferLength] = { 0 };
    int heads = 0;
    int tails = 0;

    printf("1");

    histogram_data->signal_caught = false;

    signal(SIGINT, signal_handler);

    printf("2");

    //Get the key to the allocated shared memory
    shared_memory_key = ftok("/tmp", 'M');
    if(shared_memory_key == -1)
    {
        printf("(CONSUMER) Cannot allocate key.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("3");

    //Look for shared memory every 10 seconds until it finds it
    while(true)
    {
        if((shared_memory_id = shmget(shared_memory_key, sizeof(histogram_data), 0)) == -1)
        {
            printf("4");
            printf("(CONSUMER) Shared Memory does not exist. Please run the Producer program.\n");

            sleep(kSleepTime);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("5");
            break;
        }
    }

    printf("(CONSUMER) Our Shared Memory ID is %d.\n", shared_memory_id);

    //Attach the structure to the shared memory
    histogram_data = (HistogramData*) shmat(shared_memory_id, NULL, 0);
    if(histogram_data == NULL)
    {
        printf("(CONSUMER) Cannot attach to Shared Memory.\n");
        return 3;
    }

    semaphore_id = sem_open("/HISTOGRAM_SEM", O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR, 1);

    signal(SIGALRM, alarm_handler);

    //Set the watchdog timer to 2 seconds.
    alarm(kAlarmSeconds);

    //Detach from shared memory
    shmdt(histogram_data);

    return 0;
}



void signal_handler(int signal_number)
{
    printf ("(CONSUMER) Received a signal. SIGINT ID is %d\n", signal_number);

    histogram_data->signal_caught = true;

    // Send SIGINT to Producer2
    kill(histogram_data->producer2_pid, SIGINT);

    // Send SIGINT to Producer1
    kill(histogram_data->producer1_pid, SIGINT);
}


void print_line(int num)
{
    int hundreds = num / 100;
    num = num % 100;
    int tens = num / 10;
    num = num % 10;
    int ones = num;


    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < hundreds; i++)
    {
        printf("*");
    }
    for(i = 0; i < tens; i++)
    {
        printf("+");
    }
    for(i = 0; i < ones; i++)
    {
        printf("-");
    }

    printf("\n");
}


void display_histogram(int letter_count[])
{
    int i = 0;

    printf("\n********** HISTOGRAM **********\n");
    for(i = 0; i < kLetterCount; i++)
    {
        printf("%c-%03d ", i + 65, letter_count[i]);
        print_line(letter_count[i]);
    }
}


void alarm_handler(int signal_number)
{
    int wait_time = 0;

    sem_wait(semaphore_id);

    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < kDCReads; i++)
    {
        int* read_index = &histogram_data->read_index;

        if(histogram_data->circular_buffer[*read_index] != 0)
        {
            int read_data = histogram_data->circular_buffer[*read_index];
            histogram_data->circular_buffer[*read_index] = 0;
            ++letter_count[read_data - 65];

            if(*read_index == kCircleBufferSize)
            {
                *read_index = 0;
            }

            if(*read_index == histogram_data->write_index)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if(signal_caught == true)
    {
        //Read and write indexes from the histogram data structure
        int* read_index = &histogram_data->read_index;
        int* write_index = &histogram_data->write_index;

        //Read data from buffer
        while(*read_index != *write_index)
        {
            if(histogram_data->circular_buffer[*read_index])
            {
                //Data read in from the circular buffer
                int read_data = histogram_data->circular_buffer[*read_index];

                //Mark element as read
                histogram_data->circular_buffer[*read_index] = 0;
                ++letter_count[read_data - 65];

                //Increment the elements
                (*read_index)++;
                if(*read_index == 256)
                {
                    *read_index = 0;
                }
                if(*read_index == *write_index)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        //Display a histogram listing
        display_histogram(letter_count);
        return;
    }

    wait_time++;
    if(wait_time >= 5)
    {
        wait_time = 0;
        display_histogram(letter_count);
    }

    //Release semaphore lock
    sem_post(semaphore_id);

    //Set the alarm for the watchdog to be two seconds
    alarm(kAlarmSeconds);

    //Reactivate watchdog signal
    signal(signal_number, alarm_handler);   
}
```

protos.h:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

#define kCircleBufferSize 256
#define kBufferLength 126
#define kLetterCount 20
#define kDCReads 60
#define kAlarmSeconds 2
#define kSleepTime 10

typedef struct HistogramData HistogramData;

struct HistogramData
{
    int read_index;
    int write_index;
    int is_wrap_around;
    pid_t producer1_pid;
    pid_t producer2_pid;

    char circular_buffer[kCircleBufferSize];

    bool signal_caught;
};


void signal_handler(int signal_number);
void print_line(int num);
void display_histogram(int letter_count[]);
void alarm_handler(int signal_number);
```

Comment: Put a `newline` in each debugging cue like `printf("1\n");` which ensures the output buffer is not discarded when the segfault happens.

Comment: If you must use printf, put `fflush()` after it to ensure that the buffer has been sent to the output before continuing.

Comment: @MichaelWalz - can we make this a requirement of all posted problems?

Comment: You can also use `fprintf( stderr, ... )` for debug output as `stderr` is unbuffered, and leave `stdout` for normal usage.

Answer (score 1):

You create histogram_data as a pointer to HistogramData, but don't create a HistogramData object. Then, when you call `histogram_data->signal_caught = false` in main, you program dereferences a NULL pointer.
Instead, allocate memory for HistogramData before using the pointer (for example, `histogram_data = malloc(sizeof *histogram_data);`). Don't forget to free it later, too.

Comment: which the OP would have found when running through the debugger :(  --- Give a man a fish, yada yada yada

Comment: Good catch, but C not C++.

Comment: Oops, I mis-edited and rolled back, sorry. But +1 earlier.

Answer (score 1):

> For some reason I am getting a segmentation fault before any of my code is actually executed in the main() function.

One of your preloaded data structures is likely to be causing overflow in the stack. You also have a lot of buffering going on to the output and, additionally, you have several places where you use `printf()` but do not append the newline `\n`to flush the console buffer. Alternatively, you can follow @sabbahillel's comment by putting `fflush()` after your `printf()` statements.